# How to handle session value issues

Tags: php, session

I am storing the project code and user id using the session variable in PHP Platform.

Whenever the user enters the data, the operations are performed along with the session values.

The problem I am facing is when the user enters the data and stays idle for few minutes in the first tab before saving and in the mean time he uses a new tab and changes another project.

While saving the first tab the session values changes as the values in the second tab.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Dear When you use the same code and same variable at a time from one browser with different tabs then it will change automatically 
I think you have manage with cookies or else or change the storage ...

Answer (score 2):

One possible way could be keep status of edits.. if someone is editing the same form. lock the form and show him message that someone is already making changes in this data..

As soon as form is open for editing purpose, make an ajax call with details of user and form token to store in DB. Form should be editable only for matching form tokens else lock the functionality.

Release the locks if form is edited or tokens no longer valid..

Answer (score 1):

try array to store session values that is some thing like `$_SESSION["project_code"]="your code value";
$sess_arr.=$_SESSION["project_code"]`...HTH